# Android KeyStore error codes

Tags: android-keystore

I'm using Android KeyStore implementation, and getting an exception trying to setEntry: java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to import secret key. Keystore error code: -6

Does anyone know where I can get information about these error codes? What exactly do they mean?

I have tried to decompile, but could not get the source code. Found the class here [AndroidKeyStoreSpi](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c58153b/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java), but it does not seem to be the right one, since line numbers do not match, and it does not help much either as it refers to a method called "importKey", which does not exist in the KeyStore class (or at least in the one I found documented).

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an error code from the underlying Keymaster (the secure hardware abstraction layer API). The error codes are found in [KeymasterDefs.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/security/keymaster/KeymasterDefs.java). In this particular case, -6 is KM_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_KEY_SIZE, which means you must have tried to import a key of an unsupported size.  I know it's been a long time, but do you recall what size key you were trying to import, and what algorithm?

Comment: I cannot remember what key size I selected, but the solution for me was to try out different combos of key sizes and algorithms. Thanks for the sc!